# can't get specific line from bash output

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

I'm trying simple bash script:

`/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

output is:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
11.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 11.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
10.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 10.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_192, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Seems to be 4 lines, but if I try to get second line:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V | sed -n 2p
```

The output is the same. No additional line. If I try the first one - I got the second:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V | sed -n 1p
```

Output:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    11.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 11.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    10.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 10.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_192, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

If I assign output to array and count it's size:

```
array=( $(/usr/libexec/java_home -V) )
array_size=${#array[@]}
echo $array_size
```

it shows size = 1:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    11.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 11.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    10.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 10.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_192, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home

1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Likely output is to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, Try `/usr/libexec/java_home -V 2>&1 | sed -n 1p` Possible the `"Matching Java.."` is to `stdout` and the rest to `stderr`. (hard to tell). You can always use `/usr/libexec/java_home -V 2>/dev/null` to eliminate what is output to `stderr` to test. If it is all to `stdout`, then there is something preventing normal word-splitting from occurring. Have you altered `IFS` in your parent shell?

Comment: `/usr/libexec/java_home -V 2>&1 | sed -n 1p` works nice! Thank you!

Comment: Sure, glad it helped. Your `sed` call was correct, so the only other likely cause was the script was outputting to `stderr` (which isn't being piped to `sed` and just appears on your screen making it look like `sed` wasn't working). Now you know what to look for when something like that pops up -- we have all learned that lesson the same way `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What appears to be happening is that your script, `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` is outputting some, or all, of its output to `stderr` instead of writing to `stdout`. Since the shell pipe (`'|'`) connects the `stdout` of the previous command to `stdin` of the command that follows, any output to `stderr` by `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` just gets written to your screen and is never processed by `sed` making it look like `sed` wasn't working.

To test and correct the problem is that is the case, just redirect `stderr` from your script to `stdout` and then pipe the result to `sed`, making sure `sed` receives all of the output from your script, e.g.

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V 2>&1 | sed -n 1p
```

Glad it helped.